# how do i copy a table from one excel to other using python

Tags: python, excel

I want to copy contents from a excel which is in the form of table to other new excel using python.I'm able to copy cell by cell but couldn't write it as a table form in new file.

Comment: Please add your code, and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you don't understand the question please ask me

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at pandas library, both for importing and exporting the table.
To import use pd.read_excel() https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html.

```
df=pd.read_excel()
```

To export use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html:

```
df.to_excel()
```

Comment: Hi,I have used the following code but i couldn't meet my requirement of copying data as table format

**import pandas as pd;
df = pd.read_excel("file path")
df.to_excel("file path")**